# Assume a is an automorphism from Z9 to Z9 and a(4)=1. What is a(7)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I was thinking a is a permutation (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) and 4 goes to 1, but then I don't know where to proceed.

Comment: Hint: What is $a(8)$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I don't know what is a(8), can you give more hint?

Comment: Hint: What is $a(4+4)$?

Comment: Note that it is better to not put the question in the title, but to describe your question in the text of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\phi(4)=1$ we know that $\phi(4)+ \phi(4)=\phi(4+4)=\phi(8)=2$ by properties of homomorphisms. If we keep adding $\phi(4)$ we will obtain different equivalence classes, do it to get $\phi(7)$.

Comment: so a(7) should be a(8)+a(8)?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: thank you! will you please look at this question too? Just the second part http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497356/problems-according-to-a-cayley-table